# Scope of disabled globbing in a shell script

Tags: linux, shell, glob, ksh

I wanted to know what the scope of a "set" command would be in a shell script.
Is it limited to the script itself? Or if run via an interactive shell, limited to that particular instance?

Specifically, I'm trying to disable globbing, execute some commands and enable it again

```
#Disable Globbing
set -o noglob

#Run some cmd's

#Enable Globbing again
set +o noglob
```

So let's say if someone else logged in on the server and tried to do something *while* my script is running, will they be affected by the "noglob" that is disabled temporarily?

PS: I do understand the best practices of Quoting variables, but would still like to know the impact of setting noglob.

Thanks

Comment: setting a shell option is effective in the current instance and its subshells only; but as you said, there's no real use-case for setting `noglob`, at least in bash.

Comment: When you say "a shell script" -- a script you _source_, or a script you _run as a subprocess_? The latter can't change the settings of your interactive shell even for a moment.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy I'm afraid I don't know enough about CLI's to answer if it runs as a _source_ or _subprocess_. What i can tell you is that the script is part of a pipeline and is compiled to run on a server which then connects to the _target server_ to actually do  stuff that's written in the script

Comment: @Ish, _by default_ almost everything is a subprocess. If you run `source somescript` or `. somescript` (note the space), then `somescript` runs in your current shell interpreter so it can change that interpreter's state and configuration (settings like `noglob`, current directory, environment variables, etc); whereas if you just run `somescript` then it's a subprocess and can only change _its own_ state, not yours. Shell functions and the few commands that are built into the shell itself (like `cd` -- that's why it can change the shell's directory) are exceptions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Although the shell is an application, like Firefox or Libre Office Writer, and `set -o noglob` is a kind of setting, it's not handled the same way. The `set -o noglob` setting is not stored into a configuration profile of the application; it is only a volatile run-time change which affects that running instance of the shell.

Permanent configuration changes to the behavior of a shell have to be manually recorded in a startup script. For instance, GNU Bash, when running interactively, will read a file called `.bashrc` in your home directory. If you put `set -o noglob` in that file, then you will have that setting in effect in every new Bash instance. Other users won't be affected because when they run Bash, it reads their own `.bashrc`.

There are global files in `/etc` where you could make changes that affect all users. To edit those you need superuser privilege.

Applications like web browsers and word processors do this for you; when you change something in their preferences, they make that setting go "live" in that instance of the program **and** they record it into some configuration file or database, so that it will be in effect if the program is restarted.